# Maintaining large number of functions jquery plugin (best practice)

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am currently working on several `jQuery` plugins. I am following this structure-

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){
    var name = "pluginName";
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element    = element;
        this.name       = name;
        this._defaults  = $.fn.pluginName.defaults;
        this.options    = $.extend({}, this._defaults, options);
        this.init();
    }

    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
        init: function() {

        },
        otherFunctions: function() {

        }

        // ...and many other functions...

    });

    $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
        this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, name)) {
                $.data(this, name, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    $.fn.pluginName.defaults = {
        // Default plugin values
    };


})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Please notice the comment

```
// and many other functions...
```

the problem arises here.

There could be too many numbers of functions here and the problem is maintaining these functions.

So is there any approach for maintaining a large number of functions. Something like

> you should write them alphabetic order.

or

> you should write the function body up and call them below.

Comment: Maybe use a module bundler instead, like webpack?

Comment: Actually, at this moment I just want to do it with jQuery only. @CertainPerformance

Comment: I understand but the project is not big enough. Say there would be 30 methods. Which is the best way to arrange them? Arrange them alphabetically or something else.